# > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac Failed config file doesnt exist

Tags: java, android

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> C:\Users\rhars\Downloads\ludobhaji\app\src\main\java\com\nmxg\ludoxt\winner\tournaments\adapter\OngoingAdapter.java:22: error: package com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config does not exist
> import com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config.config;
> ^
> C:\Users\rhars\Downloads\ludobhaji\app\src\main\java\com\nmxg\ludoxt\winner\tournaments\adapter\PlayAdapter.java:21: error: package com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config does not exist
> import com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config.config;
> ^
> C:\Users\rhars\Downloads\ludobhaji\app\src\main\java\com\nmxg\ludoxt\winner\tournaments\adapter\ResultAdapter.java:21: error: package com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config does not exist
> import com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config.config;
> ^
> C:\Users\rhars\Downloads\ludobhaji\app\src\main\java\com\nmxg\ludoxt\winner\tournaments\AppUpdaterActivity.java:11: error: package com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config does not exist
> import com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config.config;
> ^
> C:\Users\rhars\Downloads\ludobhaji\app\src\main\java\com\nmxg\ludoxt\winner\tournaments\EditProfileActivity.java:18: error: package com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config does not exist
> import com.nmxg.ludoxt.winner.tournaments.config.config;
> Please anyone helpme with this

I dont know much about this error, Im thinking that this error is showed up up beacause because there is no config file in the directory and huh I know nothing please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.